# Hypotheses check with mixed ANOVA, ANCOVA, regression or multilevel linear model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, multilevel-analysis, ancova

I conducted a repeated-measures experiment and obtained for each subject the following data:

```
IV - continous (personality trait)
DV - continous, under condition 0 (default condition)
DV - same variable as above, but under condition 1
DV - same variable as above, but under condition 2
```

From theory, I have multiple hypotheses:

- The higher `IV` in a subject is, the higher is the change of `DV` between condition 1 and 0 (`DV.1 - DV.0`).
- The higher `IV` in a subject is, the higher is the change of `DV` between condition 2 and 0 (`DV.2 - DV.0`).
- `DV` under condition 2 is higher than under condition one for subjects with a high `IV`.

What is the recommended way to check those hypotheses?

1. First I thought about using a median split on `IV` to separate it in a low/high group so that `IV` is categorial, and hence a mixed ANOVA would work (dependent variable = `DV`, whitin = condition, between = `IV`). But doing a median split loses a lot of information and might lead to wrong conclusions, so I am not happy with this. Also, I get unequal group sizes which are problematic for mixed ANOVAs. Other than that ANOVA would be good, I could just use planned contrast to check my hypotheses.
2. Then I thought about using an ANCOVA, because an ANCOVA is an ANOVA with an added continous covariate (in this case `IV`), meaning `IV` does not have to be split artificially and can stay metric. The problem here is that if I understood it correctly the ANCOVA would partial out the effect of `IV` - which would not be acceptable, because I am mainly interested in the effect of `IV` on the `DV` under different conditions.
3. I then thought I just use a simple linear regression: `lm(DV.1 ~ IV + DV.0)`, or `lm(DV.1 - DV.0 ~ IV)`. With that I can check if I get a significant regression coefficient. But how do I know whether the difference between `DV.1` and `DV.0` is significant? Because if they are not, I have to reject my first hypothesis.
4. I also thought about using a multilevel linear models to model my problem and circumvent the problems that a mixed ANOVA can only have categorial independent variables. But I am not sure if that is even possible? I thought about using `lme` in *R* with subject as a `random` argument to account for the repeated measures design. Would that work?

As you probably can tell, I am new to the world of statistics, especially to hypothesis testing. I would appreciate it if you could help me choose the right kind of analysis method for my hypotheses!

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation of your design is incorrect. You have just 1 DV (not 3) and 2 IVs (not 1). Your IVs are `trait` and `condition`. You also appear to have measured the same individual under multiple conditions, which suggests that you need a linear mixed-effects model with a random intercept (and possibly slope) for `individual`.

The simplest model that would be appropriate for this problem is (in `lmer` syntax ):

```
lmer(DV ~ trait + condition + (1|individual))
```

Of course, you may want to consider whether there could be interactions between trait and condition, and differences in how `individuals` respond to changes in `condition`